# Color of the Sky

Tags: color, atmospherics

What is the color of the sky depending on the time?

I'm looking for a set of colors (HTML-Code), the sky has during sunrise, morning, forenoon, noon, afternoon, evening and sunset. A formula to calculate the color would be awesome.

Comment: A simple lerp (linear interpolation) between a light and dark blue would work.

Comment: Even for a given time of day (and a fixed atmospheric turbidity), the color of the sky is different in different directions. [Mitsuba](https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/) uses the model of [Hosek and Wilkie](http://cgg.mff.cuni.cz/projects/SkylightModelling/), which I assume is the state of the art.

Comment: When you say "sky" do you include clouds and the sun? Just earlier tonight part of the sky was bright pink and peach for a few minutes just before the sun went down.

Comment: You probably need the altitude, time of year, latitude, longitude, etc. to achieve a perfect result. For instance, there are days on the Arctic, when it's always black

Comment: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/procedural-generation-virtual-worlds/simulating-sky/simulating-colors-of-the-sky

Comment: Are you asking about the Earth's sky?

Comment: As the other comments show, there is a very wide range of possible answers here, depending on your requirements. Could you [edit] to explain what you will be using these for, and how accurate they need to be, and whether you just want shades of blue or other sky objects like clouds, stars, sun, moon?

Comment: https://cgg.mff.cuni.cz/projects/SkylightModelling/HosekWilkie_SkylightModel_SIGGRAPH2012_Preprint.pdf

Comment: https://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/papers/sunsky/sunsky.pdf